# How to close Visual Basic Application using vba code

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to close the Visual Basic Application only? i tried the Apllication.Quit that will close Visual Basic Application and the Excel too.

How to close the Visual Basic Application only?

Below is my code.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't 'close' the VBA app only. The VBA app is part of the Excel document unless you strip it out. (i.e. disble macros) What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: i using macro call out the visual basic application. I wish to close the visual basic application after press the close button so that other people will not able to view/edit my coding.

Comment: If you want to protect your code, then just protect the VBA project. Here is [HOW](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=644)

Comment: Yes - put a password on it though of course it is easily crackable, and no ones code is so unique and precious that you need to hide it... unless you have hard coded passwords in there.

Comment: How to let people to use the visual basic application without view the code? Once user close the vba,automatic will go into coding window. I just want remain the excel file open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open the excel-file, the VBA-window is not opened, so your users cant see your code, unless they open it. So I don' really understand why you have this problem.

Anyway,  you can run this code to close it:

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
```

You have some other solutions you can find here:
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/28529-close-visual-basic-editor-window.html

Depending on your security setting you might get an error that you can read about how to solve here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282830.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want you form to go away, use `Me.Hide`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but this might help someone in the future.

So I stumbled on this looking for the answer provided and it works correctly.  However in my case I had a sub that programmatically added code to new sheets that were opened in the workbook. The issue with this was that the users saw the VBA app (since it was visible) which confused them, as such I was also looking for a way to close the VBA code window.  Adding the code from above provided by Nybee worked to prevent the issue.

```
Dim xPro As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim xCom As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim xMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim xLine As Long

Set xPro = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
Set xCom = xPro.VBComponents(ActiveSheet.CodeName)
Set xMod = xCom.CodeModule

With xMod
    xLine = .CreateEventProc("Change", "Worksheet")
    xLine = xLine + 1
    .InsertLines xLine, "Sheet_Evaluator Me"
End With

Build_Score_Card
xMod.VBE.ActiveWindow.Close
xCom.VBE.ActiveWindow.Close
xPro.VBE.ActiveWindow.Close

Set xMod = Nothing
Set xCom = Nothing
Set xPro = Nothing

ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
```